# Selenium conundrum! Store links/text in links if certain text is present in element

Tags: text, selenium, hyperlink, store

I'm VERY new to Selenium and only came across it when trying to find a way to do the following:

I am a member of website which has forum groups. The website does not have a search function where you can search for all users within a group who are, say, from the UK.

What I want to do is navigate to the user list within a certain group and have a script that looks on the page for the text "United Kingdom" (the country of origin is written next to each username) and then either stores the username or (more preferable) the link which the username points to.

I have managed to write bits that do things like, highlight the term "United Kingdom" etc. But I can't seem to figure out how you search for one piece of text, but store the link which sits in the same element.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which Selenium product do you use, Selenium RC, or Selenium WebDriver? Which language bindings do you use? Also, it would be really helpful if you posted the HTML code of the element...

Comment: Sorry, I use the Selenium Firefox plugin, Selenium IDE.
So, I've been using the GUI to create scripts, and editing them in the HTML tab.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you use java bindings, although the basic principle stays the same with other languages

```
String foo = driver.findElement(By.Id("xxx")).getAttribute("href");
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. I'll try this when I get home. If I'm still struggling, I'll post the HTML of the element. Thank you